# Is There anyway I can configure/change already created aws Resources using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Suppose I already have a beanstalk deployed using the AWS UI now I want to change some of its setting using terraform Can I do so?

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to import the beanstalk resource into Terraform using [Terraform import](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_environment)

```
terraform import
```

For the imported one you must write the Terraform configuration also as Terraform will not create configurations automatically.

Then you can make changes as per your need